# how to programmatically draw border and remove it after words around UIImageview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, border

Please read my question before marking it as duplicate or repeat question...

1. I have one scroleView in which I put some images in tabular form.
2. When user click one of it the next view controller is shown and the
       clicked image's uiview get green border.
3. And when user navigate back to this view the clicked image is shown
   with green border. all this worked fine

But the problem starts when user clicks other images : the previously clicked image doesn't get back to normal, ie, its border stays there even if I put its width to 0.0 and color to `clearColor`

Please guide me how to remove those borders

My code is as below:

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
        {
            int index = (row * 2) + col;
            if(index < [tempArr count])
            {
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10+col*(10+145),10+row*(5+100),145, 100);
                UIView *fr = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                CGRect imgFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 100);
                UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgFrame];
                imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[tempArr objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"add"]];
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
                fr.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
                fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
                if(selctedFrame == index)//Here i put border
                {
                    fr.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
                    fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
                }
                else //here i remove them
                {
                    fr.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
                    fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                }
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                [fr addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; 
                [fr addSubview:imgView];
                fr.tag = index;
                [self.scrollDisplay addSubview:fr];
                [self.scrollDisplay bringSubviewToFront:fr];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollDisplay];
```

This method is called in `viewWillAppear:animated:` method

**Edit**

[image]

after some navigation forth and back

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just need to do is to set the border color to the background color of the view. any other options did nothing the border is not been hidden through any thing else the only work around i got is this

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer-** I think the problem is that you're adding new views again and again. Instead of doing `UIView *fr = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`, find the already existing view as: `UIView *fr = [self.scrollDisplay viewWithTag:index];` and make changes to it. In effect, new imageviews are being added over the old ones which is highly inefficient, besides causing the mentioned issue. I'm assuming you've already added the views to `scrollDisplay`. You also shouldn't create new `imgView` objects again. Set tags for them that make them unique and easy to get. For eg, set the tag `999` for each `imgView` and retrieve it as:`UIImageView *imgView = [fr viewWithTag:999];` Also, get rid of `[fr addSubview:imgView];`, `[self.scrollDisplay addSubview:fr];` and `[self.view addSubview:self.scrollDisplay];` towards the end. So your code should look like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
        {
            int index = (row * 2) + col;
            if(index < [tempArr count])
            {
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10+col*(10+145),10+row*(5+100),145, 100);
                UIView *fr = [self. scrollDisplay viewWithTag:index];
                CGRect imgFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 100);
                UIImageView *imgView = [fr viewWithTag:999];
     //imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[tempArr objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"add"]]; //<--You've already set the image before so you don't need this
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
                fr.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
                fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
                if(selctedFrame == index)//Here i put border
                {
                    fr.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
                    fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
                }
                else //here i remove them
                {
                    fr.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
                    fr.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                }
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    //[fr addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; //<-- Not needed if you've already done this
    //[fr addSubview:imgView];//<-- Not needed
                fr.tag = index;
    //[self.scrollDisplay addSubview:fr];//<-- Not needed
                [self.scrollDisplay bringSubviewToFront:fr];//<-- probably not needed
            }
        }
    }
    //[self.view addSubview:self.scrollDisplay];//<-- Not needed
```

Comment: nop nothing changed just see my apps screen shots i have just added

Comment: actually on the viewWillAppear: this scroll view is created with the images and when the image is full size ie the top-left one the border will be reset but the smaller size image retain the border so i have to add the imageviews to the scrollview every time otherwise no thing is displayed on scroll view

Comment: but i got some work around as i set the border color to the background view color of the view and get the read of the border